# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: composer

Всем привет.
Проблема как я понял в файле **composer.json**

Сделал форк проекта https://github.com/wolf002/yii2-cms/tree/dev-fix и создал ветку `dev-fix` куда выгрузил свои изменения.

Далее пытаюсь выполнить `composer update` вижу ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "lowbase/yii2-cms",
"description": "Yii 2 CMS",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "cms", "lowbase"],
"homepage": "http://www.lowbase.ru/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "source": "https://github.com/lowbase/cms"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/wolf002/yii2-cms"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/Dolondro/google-authenticator"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "lowbase/yii2-user": "dev-fix",
    "lowbase/yii2-document": "*",
    "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*",
    "Dolondro/google-authenticator": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
        "setPermission": [
            {
                "runtime": "0777",
                "web/assets": "0777",
                "yii": "0755"
            }
        ],
        "generateCookieValidationKey": [
            "config/web.php"
        ]
    },
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
}
```

Так же пытаюсь установить через `composer` расширение https://github.com/Dolondro/google-authenticator 
но оно вообще не загружается.

Не смотря на то что я внес необходимые изменения в файле `composer.json`

Выполнил composer self-update
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не помогло

Comment: Наверное старая версия `composer`. Сделайте `composer install` с ново.